# HTML5 Datetime-local Displays 01-01-1970 01:00 When its empty

Tags: php, mysql, html, datetime

am building a web application and am using the html5 datetime-local  mysql to store the data and php to fetch datea from the database. The date datatype is stored with the sql datetime , not null and no default value.

But when the data is displayed by the html5 datetime-local tag , it displays 01-01-1970 01:00 in the browser when the datetime field is empty.

My question is I want to display 00-00-0000 00:00 when the field is empty.

Below is a code snippet for the html5 and php.

```
<?PHP

session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')) {

header ("Location: loginForm.php");

}

?>


<?php
include('/templates/header.php');
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "root"; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "datacentre"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "data_centre_users"; // Table name 
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if($con->connect_error){
   die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
}

// Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin";
$result = $con->query($sql);


function myDate($x){

  return strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
               strtotime($x));

}         


?>

<section id="sidebar">

</section>

<section id="content">

<div id="scroll-table">
<table >
<caption>

            </caption>
            <tr>
                <th class="center"><strong>ID</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>User Name</strong></th>
                <th class="center"><strong>Time Created</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                // output data of each row
                while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['user_name']; ?></td>  
                        <td class="center">
                         <input name="time_created" disabled="disabled" type="datetime-local" id="time_created" value="<?php echo myDate($rows                         ['time_created']); ?>" size="15">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
</table>
</div>
</section>


<aside></aside>

<?php
$con->close();

include('/templates/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: That's the start of the unix epoch (plus DST maybe). Just check if the field is empty and output accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` returns `false` when an invalid value is passed to it. When you try to format `false` you get the Unix Epoch which is Jan 1, 1970.

If you do not want that value to appear check to see if `$x` contains no value and either return an empty string or some other default value.